# Significance of order of statements when writing Combine code?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, reactive, combine

If i run the code below:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import UIKit

let textField = UITextField()
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
let publisher = array.publisher
    
//Statement 1
textField.publisher(for: \.text).sink{ print("Sink for .text property on textfield: \($0!)")}
    
//Statement 2
let subscriber = publisher.compactMap {$0}.assign(to: \.text, on: textField)

let _ = publisher.dropFirst(2).sink{print("Sink for array: \($0)")}
```

I get the output:

```
sink for .text property on textfield: 1
sink for .text property on textfield: 2
sink for .text property on textfield: 3
sink for .text property on textfield: 4
sink for .text property on textfield: 5
sink for .text property on textfield: 6
sink for .text property on textfield: 7
Sink for array: 3
Sink for array: 4
Sink for array: 5
Sink for array: 6
Sink for array: 7
```

But if I flip the order of the statements 1 and 2, the output becomes much different:

```
Sink for .text property on textfield: 7
Sink for array: 3
Sink for array: 4
Sink for array: 5
Sink for array: 6
Sink for array: 7
```

Why is that?
I tried to look into Combine documentation but couldn't find an answer that makes sense.

Comment: array.publisher publishes all values before you subscribe to the publisher on textField so you just receive the last value

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
let publisher = array.publisher
```

You create a publisher that is going to emit those values **once** to any subscribers and then complete.  Once the publisher is complete, it will never publish a value again.

When you move statement 2 to the top, that sink will consume all the values in the publisher and leave the last value in the "current value subject" of the text field. Then when you subscribe to the current value subject you see the "7" published from that.

You can reproduce that effect without a text field that makes the `CurrentValueSubject` more explicit:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

let stringPulisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
let publisher = array.publisher

//Statement 2
let subscriber = publisher.compactMap {$0}.sink{ stringPulisher.send($0) }

//Statement 1
stringPulisher.sink{ print("Sink for .text property on textfield: \($0)")}

let _ = publisher.dropFirst(2).sink{print("Sink for array: \($0)")}
```

Comment: I have a question that may be out of scope of this discussion, but does sink run asynchronously? I tried with 1000 items instead of 7 and it still exhibited the same behaviour.

Comment: Put a break point on a statement inside the `sink` call and see what thread it's executing on.  Then create a dispatch queue and put a `receiveOn` modifier before `sink` and see what happens.  Then put a `sendOn` modifier before `compactMap` and try that.